# "Indirect" ManyToMany Relation

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Warning:  I am brand new to NHibernate!

I have a User object.  This User object has related Roles.  These Roles have related Privileges.  The goal is to get a list of Privileges for a User.  Privileges are "indirectly" related to Users through Roles.

When doing a select on the user to get the list of related Privileges I might get back multiples of a Privilege.  So I do a UNIQE select.

I am wondering if it is possible to have some 'magic' NHibernate mapping that will fill my Roles list AND my Privilege list.  The easy part I solved myself (proud! ;-) ) is mapping correctly the Roles.  I have no idea how to get the 'indirectly' related (unique) Privileges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; private set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Privilege> Privileges
    {
        get { return Roles.SelectMany(role => role.Priveleges).Distinct(); }
    }

    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<CompanyRole>();
    }
}
```

and query like

```
session.QueryOver<User>()
    .Fetch(u => u.Roles).Eager
    .Fetch(u => u.Roles.Privileges).Eager
```